# How does isolate scope work in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem in understanding the `scope : {}`. Below is the code sample i am working on. Why does it always print in console `"strength"` instead of its corresponding array value.

// Code goes here

```
var app = angular.module("superApp", []);

app.directive("superhero", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",

        controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.abilities = []

        this.addStrength = function() {
            $scope.abilities.push("strength")
        }

        this.addSpeed = function() {
            $scope.abilities.push("speed")
        }

        this.addFlight = function() {
            $scope.abilities.push("flight")
        }
    },

    link: function(scope, element) {
        element.addClass("button");
        element.bind("mouseenter", function() {
            console.log(scope.abilities);
        })
    }
  }
});
```

Below is the `entire working code`.
http://plnkr.co/edit/jv2xZRvx4X8IcjKKkiXU?p=preview

It always prints `"strength"`, regardless of the hover. The moment i add `scope: {}`, it prints its corresponding values.

I am not understanding here, is what does the `scope: {}` do the magic here?. What is **isolated** here? I am totally confused here.

Comment: Isolate Scope - `scope: {}` isolates the outer scope from the inner scope, in a sense that your directive only has access to aliased variables passes explicitly to it. Read about it directly in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-)

Answer (score 2):

This is the problem:

```
$scope.abilities = [];
```

Without isolate scope, you're clearing the common abilities list every time you instantiate the controller - and it gets instantiated once for each directive.

See what happens when you don't overwrite the abilities: http://plnkr.co/edit/5MJSXYogsuoVAbyQTiA5?p=preview. Still not good - they pile up. That's why isolate scope should be used, so that **no scope properties are inherited from parent controllers**: http://plnkr.co/edit/2zh5923hS6MRM2jczIKv?p=preview

[This video](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-understanding-isolate-scope) might help you understand isolate scopes better along with the [official docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) (you'll see the video example is quite similar to yours).

Answer (score 1):

Without `scope: {}`, all of your directives are sharing the same scope which means sharing the same `scope.abilities`, so your last directive `strength` initializes `scope.abilityes = []` and only push 'strength' in.

With `scope: {}`, every time `superhero` is loaded with an isolated scope and isolated `scope.abilities`, so it always keeps the initialization with three elements in.

You can `console.log(scope.$id)` in directive to check the difference.

Comment: So, without scope : {}, superhero directive is shared thrice to other directives with same scope and with scope: {}, the superhero  directive is shared thrice other directives with individual scopes.

Comment: Exactly, and to be more specified, 'share' means you 'require' some other directive in current directive.